# Wireguard cant read wg0.conf on share

Tags: fedora, selinux, libvirt, wireguard

I have a virtual fedora server running using libvirt and have shared a directory from the host using `virtiofs`.

```
hostshare /etc/wireguard virtiofs rw,relatime 0 0
```

The dir in the guest is mapped to `/etc/wireguard` and the permission at both the host and guest for the shared folder is `root:root (id:0)`.

When I create the `wg0.conf` file inside this dir, the systemd service fails.

```
Dec 11 12:59:11 vpn-server systemd[1]: Starting wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
Dec 11 12:59:11 vpn-server wg-quick[889]: wg-quick: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf' does not exist
Dec 11 12:59:11 vpn-server systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 11 12:59:11 vpn-server systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 11 12:59:11 vpn-server systemd[1]: Failed to start wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
```

However, if I run `wg-quick up wg0`, then wireguard starts.

```
# wg-quick up wg0
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.0.0.1/24 dev wg0
[#] ip -6 address add fdf0:426a:74ae::1/64 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
[#] ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I have checked the systemd service is waiting for the mount to exist by adding the mount to the `After` parameter in the service, however, even trying to start it manually after the system is up and I've confirmed the share is accessible, the service still fails to start.

Can anyone help me to realise what is going wrong, please?

It looks like the mount point isnt being seen by the systemd service

```
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: /dev/mapper/fedora-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=4096k,nr_inodes=368069,mode=755,inode64)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,inode64)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,size=594992k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755,inode64)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=3915)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,pagesize=2M)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: hostshare on /etc/wireguard type virtiofs (rw,relatime)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,nr_inodes=1048576,inode64)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: /dev/vda2 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=297496k,nr_inodes=74374,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server mount[1326]: tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)

Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server wg-quick[1327]: wg-quick: `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf' does not exist
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

UPDATE

As pointed out by @MarcusMüller, looks like a selinux issue

```
Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server audit[1327]: AVC avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1327 comm="wg-quick" name="/" dev="virtiofs" ino=981467275 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

The good news is if I put selinux into permissive mode`(setenforce 0)`, the wg service starts.

Comment: is it possible that the wireguard service gets started before the virtiofs share is set up?

Comment: @MarcusMüller thats why i added the `etc-wireguard.mount` in the `After` parameter of the service. It's not the issue because even now with the server started for several minutes, I still cant start the service but i can access the share.

Comment: hm, right, sorry. Nothing in `journalctl` about possible SELinux violations, right?

Comment: `Dec 11 13:21:50 vpn-server audit[1327]: AVC avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1327 comm="wg-quick" name="/" dev="virtiofs" ino=981467275 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0`

Comment: bingo! (maybe). `audit2allow` might be the best solution here!

Comment: hmm its not installed or in dnf. any ideas? (Fedora 39)

Comment: It's in the policycoreutils-python-utils package

Comment: I go in to the solution in another post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/764814/selinux-policy-not-applying/764815#764815

Comment: Cool! Could you post a really short answer here, as well, that says something like "…was caused by SELinux not allowing… solved by fixing … as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/764814/selinux-policy-not-applying/764815#764815"? That way, you could close this question as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by an SELINUX permissions issue as pointed out by [@Marcus Müller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/106650/marcus-m%C3%BCller).

I have described the solution in another question, however, in short, you need to use `audit2allow` to work out the permissions and then apply them using `semanage`.

See this question for a fuller answer

[SELINUX policy not applying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/764814/selinux-policy-not-applying/764815#764815)