# SELINUX policy not applying

Tags: selinux

I have a Fedora Server v39 (minimal install) running as a VM (host is also Fedora Server v39).

I have shared a host directory with the VM using `virtiofs` and mapped it to `/etc/wireguard` in the VM.

```
drwx------. 4 root root system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0                   109 Dec 13 22:03 wireguard
```

I have installed `wireguard` which reads its config from `/etc/wireguard`, except SELINUX is blocking

```
# ausearch -m AVC -i
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 21:19:26.166:194) : avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1151 comm=wg-quick name=/ dev="virtiofs" ino=981467275 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:00:40.880:204) : avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1250 comm=wg-quick name=/ dev="virtiofs" ino=981467275 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:01:47.028:208) : avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1265 comm=wg-quick name=/ dev="virtiofs" ino=981467275 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:01:47.028:209) : avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1265 comm=wg-quick path=/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf dev="virtiofs" ino=981467299 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:01:47.033:210) : avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1269 comm=stat path=/etc/wireguard dev="virtiofs" ino=981467275 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:01:47.034:211) : avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1265 comm=wg-quick name=wg0.conf dev="virtiofs" ino=981467299 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:01:47.034:212) : avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=1265 comm=wg-quick path=/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf dev="virtiofs" ino=981467299 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:01:47.035:213) : avc:  denied  { ioctl } for  pid=1265 comm=wg-quick path=/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf dev="virtiofs" ino=981467299 ioctlcmd=TCGETS scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:30:26.574:372) : avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1692 comm=wg-quick name=/ dev="virtiofs" ino=981467275 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:30:26.574:373) : avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1692 comm=wg-quick path=/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf dev="virtiofs" ino=981467299 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:30:26.584:376) : avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1702 comm=stat name=/ dev="virtiofs" ino=981467275 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:30:26.588:377) : avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1704 comm=stat path=/etc/wireguard dev="virtiofs" ino=981467275 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:30:26.588:378) : avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1692 comm=wg-quick name=wg0.conf dev="virtiofs" ino=981467299 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:30:26.589:379) : avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=1692 comm=wg-quick path=/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf dev="virtiofs" ino=981467299 scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(13/12/23 22:30:26.593:380) : avc:  denied  { ioctl } for  pid=1692 comm=wg-quick path=/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf dev="virtiofs" ino=981467299 ioctlcmd=TCGETS scontext=system_u:system_r:wireguard_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:virtiofs_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
```

So I installed `policycoreutils-python-utils` to get SELINUX tools and ran `grep AVC /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M wireguard` to get me the following policy

```
# cat wireguard.te

module wireguard 1.0;

require {
    type wireguard_t;
    type virtiofs_t;
    class dir { getattr search };
    class file { getattr ioctl open read };
}

#============= wireguard_t ==============
allow wireguard_t virtiofs_t:dir { getattr search };
allow wireguard_t virtiofs_t:file { getattr ioctl open read };
```

However, when I try to install it, I get an error

```
# semodule -i wireguard.pp
libsemanage.semanage_direct_install_info: Overriding wireguard module at lower priority 100 with module at priority 400.
Failed to resolve typepermissive statement at /var/lib/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/400/permissive_wireguard_t/cil:1
Failed to resolve AST
semodule:  Failed!
```

I'm now at a loss as every help page I find says to do it this way... any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok.. very simple solution.  It turns out you cant name the policy the same as the type!

So, the line to change in the above process is simply:

```
grep AVC /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M wireguard-policy
```

And then apply it with

```
semodule -i wireguard-policy.pp
```